# Spring Data JPA - concurrent Bulk inserts/updates

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

at the moment I develop a Spring Boot application which mainly pulls product review data from a message queue (~5 concurrent consumer) and stores them to a MySQL DB. Each review can be uniquely identified by its reviewIdentifier (String), which is the primary key and can belong to one or more product (e.g. products with different colors). Here is an excerpt of the data-model:

```
public class ProductPlacement implements Serializable{

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "product_placement_id")
   private long id;

   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="productPlacements")
   private Set<CustomerReview> customerReviews;
}

public class CustomerReview implements Serializable{

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "customer_review_id")
   private String reviewIdentifier;

   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(
        name = "tb_miner_review_to_product",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_review_id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_placement_id")
        )
   private Set<ProductPlacement> productPlacements;
}
```

One message from the queue contains 1 - 15 reviews and a productPlacementId. Now I want an efficient method to persist the reviews for the product. There are basically two cases which need to be considered for each incomming review:

1. The review is not in the database -> insert review with reference to the product that is contained in the message
2. The review is already in the database -> just add the product reference to the Set productPlacements of the existing review.

Currently my method for persisting the reviews is not optimal. It looks as follows (uses Spring Data JpaRespoitories):

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void saveAllReviews(List<CustomerReview> customerReviews, long productPlacementId) {
    ProductPlacement placement = productPlacementRepository.findOne(productPlacementId);
    for(CustomerReview review: customerReviews){
        CustomerReview cr = customerReviewRepository.findOne(review.getReviewIdentifier());
        if (cr!=null){
            cr.getProductPlacements().add(placement);
            customerReviewRepository.saveAndFlush(cr);
        }   
        else{
            Set<ProductPlacement> productPlacements = new HashSet<>();
            productPlacements.add(placement);
            review.setProductPlacements(productPlacements);
            cr = review;
            customerReviewRepository.saveAndFlush(cr);
        }

    }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. I sometimes get constraintViolationExceptions because of violating the unique constraint on the "reviewIndentifier". This is obviously because I (concurrently) look if the review is already present and than insert or update it. How can I avoid that?
2. Is it better to use save() or saveAndFlush() in my case. I get ~50-80 reviews per secound. Will hibernate flush automatically if I just use save() or will it result in greatly increased memory usage?

**Update to question 1:** Would a simple @Lock on my Review-Repository prefent the unique-constraint exception?

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
CustomerReview findByReviewIdentifier(String reviewIdentifier);
```

What happens when the findByReviewIdentifier returns null? Can hibernate lock the reviewIdentifier for a potential insert even if the method returns null?

Thank you!

Comment: to get rid of race conditions, either make `saveAllReviews()` synchronized or implement explicit locking based on the key of the review (property which is constrained). In our organization, we also need to deal with such situations. Over 3+ years of trying and testing we're unable to find a method better than locking by key... maybe there is another practice, and I'd also like to learn it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you think there is a difference in making the method synchronized and locking the key (performance-wise)

Comment: of course key-locking will be much more effective, because you can safely allow concurrent writes for different keys. But this approach will require implementation efforts. You may first try `synchronized`, then think about more advanced techinque if performance doesn't satisfy.

Answer (score 4):

From a performance point of view, I will consider evaluating the solution with the following changes.

1. **Changing from bidirectional ManyToMany to bidirectional OneToMany**

I had a same question on which one is more efficient from DML statements that gets executed. Quoting from [Typical ManyToMany mapping versus two OneToMany](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1042886).

The option one might be simpler from a configuration perspective, but it yields less efficient DML statements.

> Use the second option because whenever the associations are controlled by @ManyToOne associations, the DML statements are always the most efficient ones.

---

2. **Enable the batching of DML statements**

Enabling the batching support would result in less number of round trips to the database to insert/update the same number of records.

Quoting from [batch INSERT and UPDATE statements](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/)

> hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 50
>   hibernate.order_inserts = true
>   hibernate.order_updates = true
>   hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data = true

---

3. **Remove the number of saveAndFlush calls**

The current code gets the `ProductPlacement` and for each `review` it does a `saveAndFlush`, which results in no batching of DML statements.

Instead I would consider loading the `ProductPlacement` entity and adding the `List<CustomerReview> customerReviews` to the `Set<CustomerReview> customerReviews` field of `ProductPlacement` entity and finally call the `merge` method once at the end, with these two changes:

- Making `ProductPlacement` entity owner of the association i.e., by moving `mappedBy` attribute onto `Set<ProductPlacement> productPlacements` field of `CustomerReview` entity.
- Making `CustomerReview` entity implement `equals` and `hashCode` method by using `reviewIdentifier` field in these method. I believe `reviewIdentifier` is unique and user assigned.

Finally, as you do performance tuning with these changes, baseline your performance with the current code. Then make the changes and compare if the changes are really resulting in the any significant performance improvement for your solution.

Comment: While this all improves performance, no doubt, how it helps to avoid race conditions on concurrent find-insert cycles?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou That is true. This mainly address the performance aspect of the problem. For the race condition, I would incline towards the synchronized approach as but I am wondering if there could be any better way, but not sure at this point.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu Thanks for your input. I also thought about making the productPlacement the owner side of the relationship, but lets say one product has 2.5k reviews. Wouldn't that result in fetching 2.5k reviews for adding 10 to the set? Is it possbile to add items to a lazy loaded collection?

Comment: @JuHarm89 yeah,would result in fetching all the reviews in that case. How about - Since the `reviewIdentifier` is manually assigned for the new `Customerreview` at some point in the code, we can add `boolean isNew` transient field in the `Customerreview` that will be set to `true/false` based on whether it is a new review or not. And while saving the `reviews` in the above code we could use `HQL` to perform insert review for `new` and make the mapping row. Looks more efficient think could solve the constraintViolationException as well.One downside though, is SLC is invalidated with HQL.