# How to do bulk (multi row) inserts with JpaRepository?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, cockroachdb

When calling the `saveAll` method of my `JpaRepository` with a long `List<Entity>` from the service layer, trace logging of Hibernate shows single SQL statements being issued per entity.

Can I force it to do a bulk insert (i.e. multi-row) without needing to manually fiddle with `EntityManger`, transactions etc. or even raw SQL statement strings?

With multi-row insert I mean not just transitioning from:

```
start transaction
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1, 2)
end transaction
start transaction
INSERT INTO table VALUES (3, 4)
end transaction
start transaction
INSERT INTO table VALUES (5, 6)
end transaction
```

to:

```
start transaction
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1, 2)
INSERT INTO table VALUES (3, 4)
INSERT INTO table VALUES (5, 6)
end transaction
```

but instead to:

```
start transaction
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)
end transaction
```

In PROD I'm using CockroachDB, and the difference in performance is significant.

Below is a minimal example that reproduces the problem (H2 for simplicity).

---

`./src/main/kotlin/ThingService.kt`:

```
package things

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue

interface ThingRepository : JpaRepository<Thing, Long> {
}

@RestController
class ThingController(private val repository: ThingRepository) {
    @GetMapping("/test_trigger")
    fun trigger() {
        val things: MutableList<Thing> = mutableListOf()
        for (i in 3000..3013) {
            things.add(Thing(i))
        }
        repository.saveAll(things)
    }
}

@Entity
data class Thing (
    var value: Int,
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var id: Long = -1
)

@SpringBootApplication
class Application {
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

---

`./src/main/resources/application.properties`:

```
jdbc.driverClassName = org.h2.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:h2:mem:db
jdbc.username = sa
jdbc.password = sa

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create

spring.jpa.generate-ddl = true
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 10
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data = true
```

---

`./build.gradle.kts`:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.2.30"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.0.2.RELEASE"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version kotlinVersion
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring") version kotlinVersion
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa") version kotlinVersion
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.5.RELEASE"
}

version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-core")
    compile("com.h2database:h2")
}
```

---

Run:

```
./gradlew bootRun
```

Trigger DB INSERTs:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/test_trigger
```

Log output:

```
Hibernate: select thing0_.id as id1_0_0_, thing0_.value as value2_0_0_ from thing thing0_ where thing0_.id=?
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: select thing0_.id as id1_0_0_, thing0_.value as value2_0_0_ from thing thing0_ where thing0_.id=?
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: select thing0_.id as id1_0_0_, thing0_.value as value2_0_0_ from thing thing0_ where thing0_.id=?
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: select thing0_.id as id1_0_0_, thing0_.value as value2_0_0_ from thing thing0_ where thing0_.id=?
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: select thing0_.id as id1_0_0_, thing0_.value as value2_0_0_ from thing thing0_ where thing0_.id=?
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: select thing0_.id as id1_0_0_, thing0_.value as value2_0_0_ from thing thing0_ where thing0_.id=?
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: select thing0_.id as id1_0_0_, thing0_.value as value2_0_0_ from thing thing0_ where thing0_.id=?
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: select thing0_.id as id1_0_0_, thing0_.value as value2_0_0_ from thing thing0_ where thing0_.id=?
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: select thing0_.id as id1_0_0_, thing0_.value as value2_0_0_ from thing thing0_ where thing0_.id=?
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: select thing0_.id as id1_0_0_, thing0_.value as value2_0_0_ from thing thing0_ where thing0_.id=?
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: select thing0_.id as id1_0_0_, thing0_.value as value2_0_0_ from thing thing0_ where thing0_.id=?
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: select thing0_.id as id1_0_0_, thing0_.value as value2_0_0_ from thing thing0_ where thing0_.id=?
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: select thing0_.id as id1_0_0_, thing0_.value as value2_0_0_ from thing thing0_ where thing0_.id=?
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: select thing0_.id as id1_0_0_, thing0_.value as value2_0_0_ from thing thing0_ where thing0_.id=?
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: insert into thing (value, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into thing (value, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into thing (value, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into thing (value, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into thing (value, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into thing (value, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into thing (value, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into thing (value, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into thing (value, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into thing (value, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into thing (value, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into thing (value, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into thing (value, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into thing (value, id) values (?, ?)
```

Comment: Please check my answer, hope it will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50694902/5380322

Comment: @Cepr0 Thanks, but I'm already doing this (accumulating in a list and calling `saveAll`. I just added a minimal code example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you set `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` property?

Comment: @Cepr0 Yes. (see above)

Comment: It's incorrect, it must be in this form: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size`

Comment: @Cepr0 Thanks, rieckpil already [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50772230/how-to-do-bulk-inserts-with-jparepository?noredirect=1#comment88562812_50772262) that and I adjusted my code accordingly. However it is still not batching.

Comment: What you are showing is batch insert. Bulk insert is a much faster technique, but it is specific to the database and it is not supported by JPA.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

To get a bulk insert with Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA you need only two things:

1. set the option `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` to appropriate value you need (for example: 20).
2. use `saveAll()` method of your repo with the list of entities prepared for inserting.

Working example is [here](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-jpa-batch-insert-demo).

Regarding the transformation of the insert statement into something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)
```

the such is available in PostgreSQL: you can set the option `reWriteBatchedInserts` to true in jdbc connection string:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db?reWriteBatchedInserts=true
```

then jdbc driver will do [this transformation](https://vladmihalcea.com/postgresql-multi-row-insert-rewritebatchedinserts-property/).

Additional info about batching you can find [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/).

**UPDATED**

Demo project in Kotlin: [sb-kotlin-batch-insert-demo](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-kotlin-batch-insert-demo)

**UPDATED**

> [Hibernate disables insert batching at the JDBC level transparently if you use an `IDENTITY` identifier generator.](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch15.html)

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to get your Kotlin demo running, but did not yet succeed. I do `git clone https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-kotlin-batch-insert-demo`, `cd sb-kotlin-batch-insert-demo` and `mvn package` but then end up with the following error: https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/7f1163110b52876f171d43e17af0853c

Comment: @Cepr0, I just tried your program with mySql db but it does not work as expected. Is there anything to do with driver. Here is a property that I am using,

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: @ShaunakPatel What exactly doesn't work and in which program, java or kotlin?

Comment: @Cepr0 in Java. I see only one difference compared to your program. 1) Database (I am using MySQL). Mean, I am running your code against MySQL

Comment: Is there one way to intercept or listen to list of saveAll(List..) method? –

Comment: What to use if I have no saveAll()? Spring Boot 1.5.1.RELEASE.

Comment: Batching with strong and JPA https://medium.com/@clydecroix/batching-database-writes-in-spring-479bee626fbf?sk=8ee224e83a830a6cce92fa4e3e76967e

Comment: Is it possible to also use a ON CONFLICT (I'll like to ignore them in my situation). My constraint is set for a unique fields combination

Comment: Thanks this worked.. Was trying for few hours..!!!

Comment: @Cepr0 `Regarding the transformation of the insert statement into something like this`...
If I understand correctly, I can't get the benefit of batching my insert/update statements if I'm not using PostgreSQL with reWriteBatchedInserts=true. Is this statement correct? Is there another form of batching that doesn't include writing the values in a comma-delimited fashion?

Comment: Is reWriteBatchedInserts available for SQL server?

Answer (score 20):

The underlying issues is the following code in SimpleJpaRepository:

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

In addition to the batch size property settings, you have to make sure that the class SimpleJpaRepository calls persist and not merge. There are a few approaches to resolve this: use an `@Id` generator that does not query sequence, like

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
var id: Long
```

Or forcing the persistence to treat the records as new by having your entity implement Persistable and overriding the `isNew()` call

```
@Entity
class Thing implements Pesistable<Long> {
    var value: Int,
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var id: Long = -1
    @Transient
    private boolean isNew = true;
    @PostPersist
    @PostLoad
    void markNotNew() {
        this.isNew = false;
    }
    @Override
    boolean isNew() {
        return isNew;
    }
}
```

Or override the `save(List)` and use the entity manager to call `persist()`

```
@Repository
public class ThingRepository extends SimpleJpaRepository<Thing, Long> {
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    public ThingRepository(EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(Thing.class, entityManager);
        this.entityManager=entityManager;
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Thing> save(List<Thing> things) {
        things.forEach(thing -> entityManager.persist(thing));
        return things;
    }
}
```

The above code is based on the following links:

- http://www.hameister.org/SpringBootUsingIdsForBulkImports.html
- http://www.hameister.org/SpringBootBulkImportWithCrudRepository.html
- https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-do-batch-processing-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: Thanks Jean for sharing useful links. But there is still an issue with persisting the `@Generated` `@Id` values using the `Persistable` method. The batch is only executed when I manually set the `id` field by my own logic. If I rely on `@Generated` for my `Long` `id` property, then the statements do no run in batches. All the links shared by you don't use `@Generated` type strategy with `Persistable` method. I even checked the Github code link that is provided in the 2nd link, but it also is assigning the `id` property manually.

Comment: I think this reply wasn't really understood (and appreciated enough). I found out the same problem with saveAll myself. So to rephrase the issue: if you HAVE working batching, your entity does NOT use generated ID, and you use SimpleJpaRepository with saveAll, then: 1.saveAll will use save in loop 2. save will call entityInformation.isNew(entity) getting response false for every call. 3. will call merge for every entity. 4. IIUC these merges calls select first, and those cannot be batched so this will create N+1 issue, due to incorrect saveAll implementation.

Comment: Batching with spring and JPA https://medium.com/@clydecroix/batching-database-writes-in-spring-479bee626fbf?sk=8ee224e83a830a6cce92fa4e3e76967e

Comment: hi, could you please check my question relate to many to many problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77257277/spring-updating-many-to-manay-reletionship/77259130?noredirect=1#comment136208510_77259130

Answer (score 9):

You can configure Hibernate to do bulk DML. Have a look at [Spring Data JPA - concurrent Bulk inserts/updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36356473/spring-data-jpa-concurrent-bulk-inserts-updates). I think section 2 of the answer could solve your problem:

> Enable the batching of DML statements Enabling the batching support
> would result in less number of round trips to the database to
> insert/update the same number of records.
>
> Quoting from batch INSERT and UPDATE statements:
>
> hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 50
>
> hibernate.order_inserts = true
>
> hibernate.order_updates = true
>
> hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data = true

**UPDATE**: You have to set the hibernate properties differently in your `application.properties` file. They are under the namespace: `spring.jpa.properties.*`. An example could look like the following:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 50
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts = true
....
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it out, but it did not work. I've added a minimal code example to my question to reproduce the problem, even with your settings.

Comment: Thanks, I adjusted my configuration (and updated my question accordingly), but still no luck.

Comment: have you tried it with a different database or is your H2 a requirement? @TobiasHermann I would suggest trying it with a MySQL database next. Not all database driver implement the JDBC batch insert/update properly

Comment: I tried using CockroachDB 2.0.2. It supports multi-row inserts and is about 10 times faster when I manually create the needed `java.sql.PreparedStatement` in my application and send it out using the raw `java.sql.Connection` of the `javax.sql.DataSource`.

Comment: What this mean spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts?

Comment: hi, could you please check my question relate to many to many problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77257277/spring-updating-many-to-manay-reletionship/77259130?noredirect=1#comment136208510_77259130

Answer (score 4):

Hibernate uses transaction-write-behind strategy to automatically perform batch insert, update or delete.

But only setting the property ***spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=100***  will not work alone.
we also have to set the ID generator as
`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_generator")`

If we use GenerationType.AUTO or GenerationType.IDENTITY on entity in this case batch insert, update will not work. Because in this case hibernate don't know about the Id value that to be inserted, because it is generated on DB level, so  it disable the batch insertion and individual insert takes place.

So for using batch insert, update our entity should have Id generator as Sequence.

Answer (score 3):

All mentioned methods work but will be slow especially if the source for inserted data lies in some other table. Firstly, even with `batch_size>1` the insert operation will be executed in multiple SQL queries. Secondly, if the source data lies in the other table you need to fetch the data with other queries (and in the worst case scenario load all data into memory), and convert it to static bulk inserts. Thirdly, with separate `persist()` call for each entity (even if batch is enabled) you will bloat entity manager first level cache with all these entity instances.

But there's another option for Hibernate. If you use Hibernate as a JPA provider you can fallback to HQL which [supports bulk inserts](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_hql_syntax_for_insert) natively with subselect from another table. The example:

```java
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session::class.java)
session.createQuery("insert into Entity (field1, field2) select [...] from [...]")
  .executeUpdate();
```

Whether this will work depends on your ID generation strategy. If the `Entity.id` is generated by the database (for example MySQL auto increment), it will be executed successfully. If the `Entity.id` is generated by your code (especially true for UUID generators), it will fail with "unsupported id generation method" exception.

However, in the latter scenario this problem can be overcome by custom SQL function. For example in PostgreSQL I use [uuid-ossp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/uuid-ossp.html) extension which provides `uuid_generate_v4()` function, which I finally register in my custom dialog:

```java
import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType;

public class MyPostgresDialect extends PostgreSQL10Dialect {

    public MyPostgresDialect() {
        registerFunction( "uuid_generate_v4", 
            new StandardSQLFunction("uuid_generate_v4", PostgresUUIDType.INSTANCE));
    }
}
```

And then I register this class as a hibernate dialog:

```
hibernate.dialect=MyPostgresDialect
```

Finally I can use this function in bulk insert query:

```java
SessionImpl session = entityManager.unwrap(Session::class.java);
session.createQuery("insert into Entity (id, field1, field2) "+
  "select uuid_generate_v4(), [...] from [...]")
  .executeUpdate();
```

The most important is the underlying SQL generated by Hibernate to accomplish this operation and it's just a single query:

```sql
insert into entity ( id, [...] ) select uuid_generate_v4(), [...] from [...]
```

Comment: hi, could you please check my question relate to many to many problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77257277/spring-updating-many-to-manay-reletionship/77259130?noredirect=1#comment136208510_77259130

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue but I couldn't see my hibernate queries in batch, I realized that query doesn't translate to what was really querying. But to be sure that is bulking you can enable to generate statistics `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true` then you will see:

[image]

when you add the `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=100` you will start to see some differences, like less jdbc statements and more jdbc batches:

[image]

Comment: I've spent quite some time figuring out where my configuration issue is before checking the hibernate statistics when first running into this issue. Thanks for letting me know that I was not the only one not going beyond hibernate initial logs.

Comment: I have been there @void, thanks for the feedback

Comment: hi, could you please check my question relate to many to many problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77257277/spring-updating-many-to-manay-reletionship/77259130?noredirect=1#comment136208510_77259130