# Duplicate Entry Exception: Spring Hibernate/JPA cascade save Many To One

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

It is a spring application (no spring boot).
The database I am using is MySQL.
The issue I am having is when saving the entity `Driver` which has a Many to one relationship on both `Carrier` and `Location`.

What I want to do is, when I do the save on Driver. Driver along with Location and Carrier is persisted to the database. The issue I am having is when trying to save. I get duplicate key violation

**Stack trace:**

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
Feb 18, 2019 1:25:42 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Duplicate entry '910327' for key 'UK_lheij6i9eldhfhyu9j1q5fjls'
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [UK_lheij6i9eldhfhyu9j1q5fjls]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:296)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.saveAll(Unknown Source)
    at greyhound.service.GreyhoundServiceImpl.process(GreyhoundServiceImpl.java:38)
    at greyhound.Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3073)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3666)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:332)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:828)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:795)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:415)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:428)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:804)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:308)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:489)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:521)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '910327' for key 'UK_lheij6i9eldhfhyu9j1q5fjls'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:970)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1109)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1057)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1377)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1042)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
    ... 69 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Entity/Model classes:  (Have removed getters/setters)**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Driver")
public class Driver {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private int version;
    @Column(name = "driver_id")
    private Long driverId;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "middle_init")
    private String middleInitial;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
    private Carrier carrier;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
    private Location location;


@Entity
@Table(name="Carrier")
public class Carrier {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private int version;

    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @Column(name = "carrier_name")
    private String carrierName;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "carrier_id", referencedColumnName = "id")



@Entity
@Table(name="Locations")
public class Location {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private Long version;
    @Column(name = "location_id")
    private Long locationId;
    @Column(name = "location_name")
    private String locationName;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "location_id", referencedColumnName = "location_id")
    private List<Driver> drivers = new ArrayList<Driver>();


}
```

**Code preparing the entities**

```
private List<Driver> prepareEntityList(Result result) {
        List<Driver> drivers = new ArrayList<Driver>();

        for(DriverAssignment driverAssignment : result.getDriverAssignments()) {
            Location location = new Location();
            location.setLocationName(driverAssignment.getHomeLocation3());
            location.setLocationId(driverAssignment.getHomeLocation());
            Carrier carrier = new Carrier();
            carrier.setCarrierName(driverAssignment.getCarrierId());
            Driver driver = new Driver();
            driver.setDriverId(driverAssignment.getDriverId());
            driver.setFirstName(driverAssignment.getFirstName());
            driver.setLastName(driverAssignment.getLastName());
            driver.setMiddleInitial(driverAssignment.getMiddleInitial());
            driver.setCarrier(carrier);
            driver.setLocation(location);
            drivers.add(driver);
        }

        return drivers;
    }
```

Question: is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do? Expect hibernate to handle the relationships when I try to save and associate a `location` with a `driver` if it has already been saved instead of trying to save it again. 
If not, what is a suggested approach to save these entities?

**Datasource configuration**

```
@Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "greyhound" });

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/greyhound1");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

        return properties;
    }
```

**Update #2**

Have a DriverRepository like this

```
@Repository
public interface DriverRepository extends JpaRepository<Driver, Long> {

}
```

**To save:**

```
repository.saveAll(drivers);
```

**Github link**
https://github.com/mukulgoel1989/greyhound

I have added the github link in case someone is willing to give this a try.

Comment: how do you perform the actual save?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski: have updated the post with repository and save details

Comment: all the data is new data? Or is it do some of there locations/carriers already exist before calling this method?

Comment: There are two use cases: 1) On very first run, everything is new. 2) on subsequent runs incoming data could change (drivers, locations, carriers) and needs to be updated in database accordingly. 
does this clarify what you were asking?

Comment: It does. I suppose the id will be null when it's a new object? (since the id is generated according to you entities)

Comment: @mahieus yes if the object is new, the id will be null as it is generated.

Comment: I updated my answer. This is however a very simple implementation you might have to add some additional checks and some optimization but it should work

Comment: when you say subsequent run.. you mean a  new transaction? Or possibly the same one as on the first run?

Comment: override hash code and equals method in location and Carrier not include id. this may solve your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I prepared the **working** solution: [Cepr0/greyhound-demo](https://github.com/Cepr0/greyhound-demo).
I reworked your project "a little" - did it with Spring-Boot, Lombok and H2 database, just for demo purposes and to simplify it.

So, if I'm not mistaken, the task is to transform '**assignments**' (from the greyhound site):

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "oper_nbr": 1,
            "carrier_cd": "GLX ",
            "last_name": "JOHN",
            "first_name": "SMITH",
            "middle_init": null,
            "home_loc_6": 12345,
            "home_loc_3": "NLX",
            "oper_class": "T"
        },
        {
            "oper_nbr": 2,
            "carrier_cd": "GLX ",
            "last_name": "JOHN",
            "first_name": "DOE",
            "middle_init": null,
            "home_loc_6": 67890,
            "home_loc_3": "NLX",
            "oper_class": "T"
        }
    ]
}
```

to three entities: **`Driver`**, **`Location`**, and **`Carrier`** with the relations:

```
Location -1---*- Driver -*---1- Carrier
```

i.e. `Driver` has 'many-to-one' relation with `Location` and `Carrier`.

The main problem of this task is that while saving the `Driver` entity, we need to use the **already persisted** `Location` and `Carrier` entities, or use **new ones**. So to solve it we have to:

1. Prepare 3 repositories for those entities.
2. For each 'assignment' **find** related `Location` and `Carrier`.
3. If `Location` and `Carrier` are not found then create new ones.
4. Create a new `Driver` and set the found `Location` and `Carrier` or new ones having been created.
5. Persist the `Driver` (and **cascaded** persist `Location` and `Carrier` if they are not found).

The final code of method `GreyhoundService.process()`:

```java
@Transactional
public void process() {
  client.getAssignments()
      .stream()
      .forEach(a -> {
        log.debug("[d] Assignment: {}", a);

        Driver driver = new Driver();

        driver.setId(a.getDriverId());
        driver.setFirstName(a.getFirstName());
        driver.setLastName(a.getLastName());
        driver.setMiddleName(a.getMiddleName());

        driver.setLocation(
            locationRepo.findById(new Location.PK(a.getLocationId(), a.getLocationName()))
                .orElse(new Location(a.getLocationId(), a.getLocationName()))
        );

        driver.setCarrier(
            carrierRepo.findById(a.getCarrierId().trim())
                .orElse(new Carrier(a.getCarrierId().trim()))
        );

        driverRepo.saveAndFlush(driver);

        log.debug("[d] Driver: {}", driver);
      });
}
```

To minimize the size of the data in the database and the number of SQL selects I transformed the initial entities as follows:

**Driver**

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@Entity
@Table(name = "drivers")
public class Driver implements Persistable<Long> {

    @Id private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String middleName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "carrierId", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "drivers_carriers"))
    private Carrier carrier;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns(
            value = {@JoinColumn(name = "locationId"), @JoinColumn(name = "locationName")},
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "drivers_locations")
    )
    private Location location;

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Location**

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "locations")
@IdClass(Location.PK.class )
public class Location {

    @Id private Long locationId;
    @Id private String locationName;

    public PK getId() {
        return new PK(locationId, locationName);
    }

    public void setId(PK id) {
        this.locationId = id.getLocationId();
        this.locationName = id.getLocationName();
    }

    public Location(final Long locationId, final String locationName) {
        this.locationId = locationId;
        this.locationName = locationName;
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class PK implements Serializable {
        private Long locationId;
        private String locationName;
    }
}
```

**Carrier**

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "carriers")
public class Carrier {
    @Id private String carrierId;

    public Carrier(final String carrierId) {
        this.carrierId = carrierId;
    }
}
```

As you can see I used natural identifiers for `Location` and `Carrier` (and a composite one in `Carrier`). This made it possible not only to reduce the size of the data but also reduce the number of additional SQL queries that Hibernate performs when storing complex entities. When `Location` and `Carrier` tables are filled, Hibernate does not perform unnecessary queries to find them but takes their data from its own cache (you can see this in the app log).

P.S. Note that this solution is not optimal. IMO to make it better you can split the main process into two parts: the first one persists distinct `Location`s and `Carrier`s and the second one just persists `Driver`s without finding `Location`s and `Carrier`s. Both parts perform with [batch insert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882952/5380322).

**UPDATE**

Branch with the optimal solution: [Cepr0/greyhound-demo:async_and_batch_insert](https://github.com/Cepr0/greyhound-demo/tree/async_and_batch_insert)

Due to the asynchronous persisting of Locations and Carriers and with batch insert, processing takes only about 5 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for taking time out for all the explanation and a working solution.

Comment: @MukulGoel You're welcome! You can also accept my answer.. ))

Answer (score 1):

duplicate problem is causing when it goes to insert entries for both sides.
The solution is to mark one side as 'mappedby' the other.

so use in `Carrier` Class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="carrier")
@JoinColumn(name = "carrier_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private List<Driver> drivers = new ArrayList<Driver>();
```

And in `Location` Class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="location")
@JoinColumn(name = "location_id", referencedColumnName = "location_id")
private List<Driver> drivers = new ArrayList<Driver>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `Location` and `Carrier` are versioned and you don't set the version in the instances you create, Hibernate probably just considers them new and tries to insert them (otherwise, if they'd need to be updated, Hibernate would anyway not know which versions to compare since it's missing in the updated instances).

Firstly, you need either to:

- fetch existing `Location` and `Carrier` instances from db and update them if they're not new (you know that by checking if id is set);
- or properly propagate and set version attribute as well together with id and business attributes.

Secondly, you also have two choices with your current entity mappings (and the stated goal to let Hibernate save the entire graph properly):

- if you don't use transactions, then for both of the above you have to resort to `entityManager.merge(driver)` so that everything is properly either inserted or updated;
- otherwise and only if you pick the first option above and read existing `Location` and `Carrier` instances and call `repository.saveAll(drivers)` in the same transaction, then it would work, because driver instances would be persisted and `PERSIST` operation would be cascaded to still attached location and carrier instances.

There are (many) other possibilities depending on the architectural choices and conventions used in you project, i.e. I would never cascade ALL from `many` side to `one` side (an example undesired consequence is removal), and I would in most cases always explicitly save the `one` side separately, but it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to populate `Carrier` and `Location` with the crated `Driver`:

```
  for(DriverAssignment driverAssignment : result.getDriverAssignments()) {
        Location location = new Location();
        Carrier carrier = new Carrier();
        Driver driver = new Driver();
        driver.setCarrier(carrier);
        driver.setLocation(location);

        // add this
        location.getDrivers().add(driver);
        carrier.getDrivers().add(driver);

        drivers.add(driver);
    }
```

this needs to be done due to the bi-directional mapping you used (`@OneToMany`)

**Update**:

Use JPA cascade config, not Hibernate one:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Carrier carrier;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Location location;
```

**Update 2**

After taking closer look at your project it seems that you are missing a transactional set-up on:

```
@Transactional
public void process() {
```

inside that method you are performing many repository operations which is fine as all SimpleJpaRepository methods are transactional.

The problem in my opinion is that **not all** of these operations are run under same transaction and effectively persistence context. (each operations runs within its own small transaction and after that all the entities are detached from the persistence context).

NOTE: you may need to play with configuration a bit to enable  @Transactional annotation set-up.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code as advised and I agree that should be there. However it did not fix the error and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I have updated the post with my datasource and entity manager configurations

Comment: add the actual save you trigger

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: Updated, No Joy.

Answer (score 0):

One way to resolve this would be to just load all the locations and carriers so with a findById() this way they are bound to you session. Use these obtained objects to be set on you new driver objects. This should resolve the issue.

```
for(DriverAssignment driverAssignment : result.getDriverAssignments()) {
  Location location;
  if (driverAssignment.getHomeLocation() != null) {
    location = locationRepo.findById(driverAssignment.getHomeLocation());
  } else {
    location = new Location();
  }
  location.setLocationName(driverAssignment.getHomeLocation3());
  Carrier carrier;
  if (driverAssignment.getCarrierId() != null) {
    carrier = carrierRepo.findById(driverAssignment.getCarrierId());
  } else {
    carrier = new Carrier();
  }
  Driver driver;
  if (driverAssignment.getDriverId() != null) {
    driver = driverRepo.findById(driverAssignment.getCarrierId());
  } else {
    driver = new Driver();
  }
  driver.setDriverId(driverAssignment.getDriverId());
  driver.setFirstName(driverAssignment.getFirstName());
  driver.setLastName(driverAssignment.getLastName());
  driver.setMiddleInitial(driverAssignment.getMiddleInitial());
  driver.setCarrier(carrier);
  driver.setLocation(location);
  drivers.add(driver);
}
```

It would look something like this. This is just a simple example because I don't know the actual context.

Comment: I have answered your question in comments above. Please refer there.

Answer (score 0):

We need to pass the identifier as a referenced column name. Map the Location entity like below.

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "location_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private List<Driver> drivers = new ArrayList<Driver>();
```