# JPA Native query puts parentheses wrong for List paremeter on INSERT INTO VALUES

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, kotlin

So I am trying to write a native named query for JPA (JPQL) to `INSERT` multiple rows of data in one go, and get back all id's of the inserted records (that don't conflict with unique constrain on the primary key). I am using a Postgres database.

Database looks like this: `SELECT * FROM table;`

```
id | sent
---+------
1  | f
(1 row)
```

What I'd like to achieve is this PSQL statement:

`INSERT INTO table VALUES (1, false),(2, false) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING id;`

Which should return:

```
id
---
2
(1 row)
```

So my initial idea was to make a native query in JPA:

```java
@Repository
interface NotificationRepository : JpaRepository<Foo, Int> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("INSERT INTO Foo VALUES (:foos) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING id", nativeQuery = true)
    fun addAllAndReturnInserted(foos: List<Foo>): List<Int>
}
```

Which works for one value in the list, but for multiple values it will create a query like:

`Hibernate: INSERT INTO Foo VALUES (?, ?) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING id`

And it throws an exception:

> PSQLException: ERROR: column "sent" is of type boolean but expression is of type int

Is there a way to transform the list into separate perentheses like `(?), (?)` instead of in one `(?, ?)` ??

Comment: You can't do that with lists. Hibernate can't know what you mean to do in a native query to try and split-up the list for you. You can have `INSERT INTO table VALUES (?, ?) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING id`

Comment: @coladict do you have another suggestion on how to build a query as described in my question?

Answer (score 4):

No, your idea is nice but will not work with Spring Data, because:

1. list parameter expansion happens only as a comma-separated list of data values `(a, b, ...)`, not a list of records or rows `(a), (b), (...)`
2. data-modifying statements that return something are also not supported (yet): https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1389

However, there is a workaround to at least the batching problem as described here:

- [How to do bulk (multi row) inserts with JpaRepository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50772230/how-to-do-bulk-multi-row-inserts-with-jparepository/50882952#50882952)