# Spring Boot - Batch updates inserts records individually instead of in a batch

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to do a batch insert (spring boot, jpa, hibernate) and when I look at the generated statistics, realized that it is still inserting them one by one instead as a batch . Below is the configuration and using JpaRepository's saveAll(collection) method. My only hunch is, I'm using an assigned primary key instead of a generated one, not sure if that is the cause.

How do I solve the problem?

**properties**

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=10
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.batch_versioned_data=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

```
   @Id
   @Column(name = "SKU")
   private String sku;
```

**Statistics:**

```
43972157 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
128270518 nanoseconds spent preparing 10 JDBC statements;
1320687164 nanoseconds spent executing 8 JDBC statements;
126666002 nanoseconds spent executing 2 JDBC batches;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
152061315 nanoseconds spent executing 2 flushes (flushing a total of 16 entities and 0 collections);
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
```

Comment: Check my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882952/5380322), hope it will be helpful...

Comment: Thanks Cepr0 , but that example uses PostgreSQL and I'm using oracle. Also, all the examples seem to be using @GeneratedValue which is not my case, I have an assigned primary key not generated one.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to adjust [`chunk`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/step.html#interceptingStepExecution) of step and [`hibernate.jdbc.batch_size`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_batch_processing) of hibernate.