# Spring Data JPA saveAll not doing batch insert

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

So I'm using a simple JpaRepository and the **saveAll()** method is called.

```
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 500
hibernate.order_inserts = true
hibernate.generate_statistics = true
```

After running the application:

```
   8045055 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    137189246 nanoseconds spent preparing 1158 JDBC statements;
    1417689514 nanoseconds spent executing 1158 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    16270990 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 1158 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
```

Can anyone see a reason for 0 having JDBC batches executed?
Also, I have to point that my entity has  **@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)** primary key

Comment: [Hibernate disables insert batching at the JDBC level transparently if you use an identity identifier generator.](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch-session-batch)

Comment: you the real MVP. This should be the accepted answer, but you posted a comment

Comment: I've posted the answer. )

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882952/5380322) my answer about batch insert will be also interesting for you...

Comment: I'm using a UUID generator on my entities and but I'm using the .save() method for a non-bulk insert and I'm still seeing the same issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hibernate doesn't perform insert batching with the identity identifier generator. 
More info is [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch-session-batch).

Comment: in my case with oracle insert batching doesn't happen with any of the id generation strategies. and yes i have set the property `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size: 100`

Comment: Does batch insert work when we are setting the Id manually?

Comment: The link to the documentation doesn't seem to offer any information about batching with id generator not working.

Answer (score 1):

Set `hibernate.order_updates = true` also.

Change the logger for `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch` to DEBUG and see what output you are getting.

Comment: Where do you set this?

Answer (score 1):

Add prefix *spring.jpa.properties* to property names. It should look like this:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 500
```