# How can I perform multi-insert in spring-data-jpa 1.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, bulkinsert

I'm using spring-data-jpa 1.x in my project and there is a bulk-insert scenario like:

```
List<Entity> entities = ...;
entities.forEach(repository::save);
```

But I have millions of entities to insert and it takes too long time due to database connection latency. I need something like:

```
repository.saveAll(entities);
```

to speed up my insertion.

Up to `spring-data-jpa:1.11.23.RELEASE` which is the latest version of spring-data-jpa 1.x, there is still no such method like `saveAll()`.

=== UPDATE ===

In spring-data-jpa 1.x the method name is `save()`:

```
<S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities)
```

=== UPDATE-2 ===

Just using `save()` (spring-data-jpa 1.x) or `saveAll()` (spring-data-jpa 2.x) can't make hibernate generate multi-insert SQL like `INSERT INTO table VALUES (?, ?, ...), (?, ?, ...), ...`. This is another topic, see: M. Deinum and Marc Ströbel's comment, or [How to do bulk (multi row) inserts with JpaRepository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50772230/how-to-do-bulk-multi-row-inserts-with-jparepository)

Comment: Why would `saveAll` won't work?  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-batch-inserts

Comment: There is `save` which takes a list (which internally calls save per element). You need to configure your JPA provider (assuming hibernate) to batch inserts/updates AND when using MySQL configure that to rewrite the query!.Also don't insert everything at once insert x elements then flush and clear your entitymanager. X you will need to determine for yourself.

Comment: there's a spring property for hibernate: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=5` https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-batch-insert-update