# How to save or update a lot of entities in a bulk/batch?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity that follows this structure:

```
name: String(not null, unique),
value: Integer(not null)
id: Long(generated, not null, unique)
```

I have a list of entities(List<>), and I want to save them to a table or update if some were already in a table, but I need an effective way to do that with some bulk/batch insert/update. Now I've tried repository.saveAll and entityManager.merge, but I get the repeated value error, as it doesn't update the values that're already in a table. What should I do?

Comment: Refer to (this) [https://vladmihalcea.com/tag/batch/] article

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to this topic:

[How to do bulk (multi row) inserts with JpaRepository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50772230/how-to-do-bulk-multi-row-inserts-with-jparepository)

To get a bulk insert with Sring Boot and Spring Data JPA you need only two things:

1. set the option `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` to appropriate value you need (for example: 20).
2. use `saveAll()` method of your repo with the list of entities prepared for inserting.

Comment: As I've already said, I cannot use saveAll(), because it throws an error, because it doesn't update the entity in the table and tries to insert a new one

Comment: Please verify you set this config:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size