# Performance insert by JPA Spring-boot with Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, performance, jpa

the first thanks for your time.

I am trying to insert data to the database by JPA(spring-boot), the project is using **Oracle**.

Currently, Insert 5000 record, it takes a long time with *repository.save(...)* or *repository.saveAll(...)*.

I tried **batch_size**, but it is not working(looks like it is not working for oracle ?).

Code config:

```
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.ddl-auto", "none");
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect");
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
            properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 5);
            properties.put("hibernate.order_inserts", true);
            properties.put("hibernate.order_updates", true);
            setJpaProperties(properties);
```

I create sql query to insert several rows at one time execute statement.

`INSERT ALL INTO table(...)...`

I hope there is a better and more efficient way

So, can you give me any solution?

Thankyou so much!!!!

Comment: Does `batch_size` affect how often changes are committed to the database? If so, "5" is probably far too small. Too many commits will definitely affect your performance. Try a much higher value, like 1000, or even 5000 (i.e. only one commit, at the end), if you can.

Comment: @pmdba batch_size help create one statement can insert serveral row data.
Like insert into table(col1, col2) values(1,2) (2,3)...
But, I tried and it is not working

Comment: How do you generate ids? Do you start outer transaction when inserting entities?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov
Ids created(based on business), just insert.

Answer (score 0):

How about:
batch_size : 1000
when entity count is 1000, then :repository.saveAndFlush();
then call the next batch.

Another method can be call the EntityManager persist directly in the batch saving. like:

```
public int saveDemoEntities(List<DemoEntity> DemoEntities) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int count = 0;
    for (DemoEntities o : DemoEntities) {
        entityManager.persist(o);
        count++;
        if (count % BATCH_COUNT == 0) {
            entityManager.flush();
            entityManager.clear();
        }
    }
    entityManager.flush();
    entityManager.clear();
    return count;
}
```

Comment: batch_size is not working. It is not generate sql with INSERT ALL INTO...., juts INSERT INTO table(...) values..(). It will take 5000 sql for 5000 records

Comment: Could you try the steps in the topic:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50772230/how-to-do-bulk-multi-row-inserts-with-jparepository?

Comment: my problem is batch_size was not working. And insert statment for oracle is difference mysql or jdbc:postgresql

Comment: Understand.  Perhaps you can call EntityManager directly for the batch save.